# Do you need Microsoft Office (Excel) to read .csv files with R?

Tags: r, csv, statistics

I just downloaded R onto my computer, but when I try to read a .csv file I get the following error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") :
>     cannot open file '[filename].csv': No such file or directory

This happens both when I command the program to read the .csv or when I try to import it manually (although that error code is slightly different).

Could this be because I don't have Microsoft Office (and subsequently, Excel) on my computer? The .csv file exists and is not corrupt because I have no problem uploading the file to Google sheets and displaying the data there. Either that, or I didn't install R correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include the code you've used, it will make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: R is run in some directory. Make sure that your `.csv` file has proper path (full like `C://Users/...` or relational like `data/my.csv`).

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need any special packages to read plain text CSV files in R.

Looking at your error message:

> Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '[filename].csv': No such file or directory

I would guess that the problem is your path to the file in question.  As a quick fix, you can try using the fully qualified path to your file.  For example, on Windows you might try this:

```
data <- read.csv(file="c:/path/to/filename.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

If this works, then the issue was the location of your CSV file.  Then, if you want to continue using a relative path, you'll have to figure out what that would be given your current R setup.